# How get unmanaged exe or dll file digital signature subject name?

Tags: c#, .net

Usually in C# when we want to get some **.net file** digital sign subject name, we just can simply use :

```
string Subject = AsseblyObject.GetModules().First().GetSignerCertificate().Subject;
```

But I want **unmanaged** exe or dll files digital signature subject name.
Is there any other way can do it? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use on digitally signed archive files (i.e. these are not managed at all):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


var signer = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile("[path to the file]");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(signer);

var certChain = new X509Chain();
certChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;
certChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = CheckRevocOffline ? X509RevocationMode.Offline : X509RevocationMode.Online;
certChain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
certChain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = VerificationFlags;

var certChainIsValid = certChain.Build(cert);

if (!certChainIsValid)
{
    //file is likely to be self signed, revoked or expired
}

var subjectName = cert.SubjectName.Name;
```

This is a stripped down version to get you started - I have a bunch more checking and exception throwing built in as well, there is a bunch of things to look out for.

Comment: @slugster, Thanks. I test it. It is good. And also thank you let me know more.